# Parachain Implementation in local PC

Tags: polkadot, substrate-parachain-template

We create a local parachain implementation in our PC followed by this steps:- (https://docs.substrate.io/test/set-up-a-test-network/) using cargo build --release steps i got error. I attached my screenshot and error message to this post.

`OS:- ubuntu-20.04LTS`[image]

```
Error Message:-
thread 'main' panicked at 'Failed to compact generated WASM binary.: Error(UnknownOpcode(192))', /home/fb-ubuntu-user/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/a3ed011/utils/wasm-builder/src/wasm_project.rs:673:14
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
error: failed to run custom build command for `polkadot-runtime v0.9.30 (https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot?branch=release-v0.9.30#06453609)`

 thread 'main' panicked at 'Failed to compact generated WASM binary.: Error(UnknownOpcode(192))', /home/fb-ubuntu-user/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/a3ed011/utils/wasm-builder/src/wasm_project.rs:673:14
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Thanks,

Comment: Review this part of the documentation, to set up your environment: https://docs.substrate.io/install/

Comment: Have you searched SE for `UnknownOpcode`? It is the fifth time this Question is asked.

Comment: Came here to ask same question

Comment: Hi @AlexBean, Thanks for your response. We have done this environment .we are trying to build parachain in local machine.we have stuck on this cargo build --release command .
please share any other docs that can help us .

Thanks